# I am trying to implement product quantity increment and decrement using react useState hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web-deployment

```
const { price, available, name, menimum } = service;
const [updatedQuantity, setUpdatedQuantity] = useState(menimum)
```

I am trying to implement useState default value is dynamically. Minimum works properly console.log when I am set useState minimum value is return NaN

```
const { price, available, name, menimum } = service;
const [updatedQuantity, setUpdatedQuantity] = useState(menimum)

const handleDecrease = () => {
    setUpdatedQuantity(pre => pre - 1)
}
const handleIncrease = () => {
     setUpdatedQuantity(pre => pre + 1)
}
```

Comment: Your state doesn't modify `menimum`. If it's `NaN` it came as `NaN` from `service`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code does:

1. Set values to four const variables from the "service" variable.
2. Set the initial state of "setUpdatedQuantity" to "menimum" - which was assigned from the "service" variable.
3. You declare increment functions.

Check the initial values of "service" if it comes with "menimum" value NaN or not.
Would be good if you can put more code for better analysis.